# input default value from api and change it to edit it. Like editing profile from instagram

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i want to display default value of an input from the api data. but when i dont change the value it reads the default state value not the api value.

i want it to work just like the edit profile on instagram.

i did this

```
<input defaultValue={transaction.resi}  onChange={(e)=> setNoResi(e.target.value)} />
<select defaultValue={transaction.courier}  onChange={(e)=> setKurir(e.target.value)} />
<input defaultValue={transaction.ongkir}  onChange={(e)=> setOngkir(e.target.value)} />
```

i managed to get the default value from api
[image]

but when i only change one of the field and not the other and input it, the field i didnt change returning the state default value which is 0, not the api default value.

any idea how to do it? any help would be appreciated. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `defaultValue` use `value` and set it to the value of your api data. I've done it like this in the past:

First I check for the event that I want to edit by looking through the api data like this:

```
const editableEvent = valueOfApiDataState.find((event) => event.id.toString() === valueOfClickedOnEvent.id
```

Now you can check if this true by putting this in a useEffect. Once it's true you can set all required values like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
if(editableEvent){
   setTitle(clickableEvent.title)
   setLocation(clickableEvent.location)
   etc..
},
[editableEvent]
})
```

**Edit for extra information:

Now you've set the title of your state to the value from your api.

```
const [title,setTitle] = useState("")
```

And in your input it will be like this:

```
<input value={title} onChange={(e)=>setTitle(e.target.value)}/>
```

Now the values you don't change won't be empty whenever you edit just one value.

Comment: so then you put the editableEvent for the value? value={editableEvent}. I need more explanation on this thnaks

Comment: You put the state of the value you want to edit as the value. In my example I use a `title` value.  So in my case the value would be title.